# Determining the attraction of a magnetic bob

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

I have a question concerning the calculation of the attraction to a ferromagnetic material in a coupled B-field, which of $N \geq3$ equally strong cylindrical permanent  magnet is produced. (experiment: magnetic pendulum)

My approach so far:

$$B(\vec{r}) = \sum_{i=1}^N B_i(\vec{r}) = \dfrac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \sum_{i=1}^N \left(\dfrac{3\vec{r}_i(\vec{m}\cdot\vec{r}_i)-\vec{m}r_i^2}{r_i^5}\right)$$

where $m$ is the magnetic moment and $r_i$ are distances of each magnet.

How do I get the force which attracts the sphere (pure iron)? I need the force to determine the trajectory of my pendulum:

[image]

This can be modeled by the [non-linear differential equation:](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetisches_Pendel) (German wiki article, no English equivalent, though there is a [Simple Wiki article](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_pendulum) on it)

$$m\ddot{\vec{r}} = \nabla(m\vec{g}\cdot \vec{r}) - \nabla\sum_{i=1}^NV_i(\vec{r})-\gamma\dot{\vec{r}}$$

where $V_i$ is the magnetic potential.

Comment: Would you be better off working in terms of magnetic potential energy? This might be easier? You also need to specify the problem far more clearly - e.g. what is "the sphere", what is the geometry?

Comment: Actually i want to determine the trajectory for my pendulum. And "the sphere" is a steel ball sorry for confusion. So to sum up i have N magnets and a steel ball hanging on a rope. And to be able to set up the differential equation i need the force which attract the bob. The magnets are all on one level and circular prepared in the rest position of the bob.